# DAX Measure to calculate MAX by Group and SUM the results but a Super Group

Tags: group-by, powerbi, sum, max, dax

I have the following table below

[image]

Name is the person in question and we have several activities listed per person. Compliant is whether that activity was compliant or not, it can only be 1 or 0. Category is the grouping of the people.

Given this information, I need to calculate the following table below in Power BI.

[image]

I need to provide a count of how many people had at least one compliant activity. Ideally this should be flexible enough that I can provide a total number how many people have at least one compliant activity. I have category as an example here, but there are slicers that I will need to use here to further drill down the data.

Comment: @DavidBacci yes it was, thank you! I was unavailable for a few days but I came back and tried your solution and it worked! Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Drag category into a table visual and then also add the following measure.

```
Measure = CALCULATE( COUNTX(VALUES('Table'[Name]), 'Table'[Name]), 'Table'[Compliant] = 1)
```

Comment: This is perfect! Exactly what I was looking for! I wanted to ask, would it be possible to calculate percentage with this measure? For example, we know with cc we have both John and Sally and only John has a compliant activity so the total is 1 for cc (as in your example). Could we calculate it such that we know there are two people for cc and only one is compliant, giving us 50%?

Comment: I don't see why not. If you get stuck, just post a new question and either myself or someone else will be able to help.